# compiling error for seemingly no reason /usr/bin/ld relocation against '.rodata'

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm 100% confused at this one because the error started happening without changing any code. It is unclear online how to use the suggested "-fPIC" fix

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Please put the text output of your shell directly in the question. Use screenshots for graphical contents, and if use the correct syntax to make them visible. BTW you can [edit] your question to do this. And please take the [tour] and provide a [example].

Comment: At least one of these must have changed: The command line you use; the object file `get_path.o`; the called compiler `gcc`, perhaps changed `PATH`; the compiling system GCC, perhaps an update. Given all the same as before when it worked there will be no error. Compiling and linking is no random process.